# Using SUM with DISTINCT

Tags: sql, postgresql

TABLE:

```
 item    value
  a        1
  a        1
  a        1
  b        2
  b        2
  c        1
  c        1
```

I want the result like this

```
 SUM
  4
```

It can be done by the following command :

```
SELECT SUM(value)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (item) *
    FROM TABLE
) s
```

But is there a simple command to do this?
Something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(value in DISTINCT(item)) FROM TABLE
```

Comment: What if the values differ for a single item? E.g. (a,1),(a,2),(a,3),(a,4)?

Comment: In my case the value of the item is unique, the data is separated because of other column that is not unique in this table (which i haven't drawn).

Comment: You will need two levels of nesting, but I think something like `select sum(value) 
from (
  select item, min(value) as value
  from items
  group by item
) t` would be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the fact that if an `item` has a different value the result set will be erroneous as pointed out in the comments, if you want to "simplify" it you could store it in a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sumDiff() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
        DECLARE
            ress integer;
        BEGIN
            SELECT SUM(value)
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT ON (item) *
                FROM itemvalues
            ) s
            INTO ress;
            RETURN ress;
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT sumDiff(); // returns 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct command would be:

```
SELECT SUM(value)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (item) *
      FROM TABLE
      ORDER BY item
     ) s ;
```

The `ORDER BY` is important when using `DISTINCT ON`.

I cannot think of way of doing this without a subquery.  In general, such data would be constructed from another query.  The summation could be done better on the base tables, rather than the result.  Hint:  The data is not normalized.